# i can’t run this code in the compiler because it keeps saying error cannot find symbol for mkitnumber

Tags: java

```
class Football {
    private String mfootballerName; 
    private int mkiitNumber;
    private String mfootballTeam;

    public String getfootballerName() {        
        return mfootballerName;
    }

    public int kitNumber() { 
        return mKitNumber;
    }

    public String footballTeam() { 
          return mfootballTeam;
    }
}
```

Comment: `mkiitNumber` is not the same as `mKitNumber`

Comment: Typo - your member is called `mkiitNumber`. Flagging as just a typographical error.

Comment: public int kitNumber() { 
        return mKiitNumber;
    }

Comment: I recommend to use an IDE like Eclipse with code completion feature. You type e.g. `mkit` and let the IDE append the rest or show you that there is no such symbol beginning with `mkit`. That virtually eliminates typos. And has many more advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo, you've mistyped your `private int mkiitNumber` as `mKitNumber` (or the other way around, depending on which you actually meant).

Here's the corrected code:

```
class Football {
    private String mfootballerName; 
    private int mkitNumber;
    private String mfootballTeam;

    public String getfootballerName() {        
        return mfootballerName;
    }

    public int kitNumber() { 
        return mKitNumber;
    }

    public String footballTeam() { 
          return mfootballTeam;
    }
}
```